# JSON Exception in Twitter Client

Tags: android, json, twitter

I am working on a Twitter Client for Android based on a tutorial, but after I do authorization on the apps, it only display the word "JSON Exception". No timeline appears.

Here is the class that contains JSONobject

```
package com.tmm.android.twitter.reader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import twitter4j.Paging;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import android.util.Log;

import com.tmm.android.twitter.util.Utility;

public class TweetReader {

    private static final String screenName = "rob_hinds";


    /**
     * a method to retrive a list of tweets from the users who the current user
     * is following
     * @return List JSON of other tweets
     */
    public static ArrayList<JSONObject> retrieveSpecificUsersTweets(Twitter twitter){
        List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();
        try {
            Paging p = new Paging(1);   //get first page only of timeline - dont want to return everything!
            statuses = twitter.getFriendsTimeline(p);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.e("Twitter", "Error retrieving tweets");
            Log.e("Twitter", e.getMessage());
        }

        return convertTimelineToJson(statuses); 
    }



    /**
     * Method that converts a list of Status' to a JSON array that can
     * be displayed by the grid view
     * 
     * @param statuses
     * @return
     */
    private static ArrayList<JSONObject> convertTimelineToJson(List<Status> statuses) {
        ArrayList<JSONObject> JOBS = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        try {
            if (statuses.size()>0){
                for (Status s : statuses){
                    String avatar = "http://" + s.getUser().getProfileImageURL().getHost() + s.getUser().getProfileImageURL().getPath();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    object.put("tweet", s.getText());
                    String timePosted = Utility.getDateDifference(s.getCreatedAt());
                    object.put("tweetDate", timePosted);
                    object.put("author", s.getUser().getName());
                    object.put("avatar", avatar);
                    object.put("userObj", s.getUser());
                    object.put("tweetId", s.getId());

                    JOBS.add(object);   
                }
            }else{
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                object.put("tweet", "You have not logged in yet! Please log on to view latest tweets");
                object.put("author", "");
                JOBS.add(object);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Log.e("JSON", "There was an error creating the JSONObject", e1);
        }
        return JOBS;
    }
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It probably fails on `object.put("userObj", s.getUser());`

You can only put a JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double, NULL, or null as value in the `put` method. `s.getUser()` is none of those.